# Why do projects that I add to my 'workspace' folder don't show up? [ECLIPSE]

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I am using Eclipse Indigo, and after having successfully extracted my project folder into my Eclipse workspace, it does not show up in the package explorer. I tried refreshing eclipse and restarting it, to no avail. I am 100% certain my eclipse is using the right directory and the project is in it.

What could be the problem? Thank you.

EDIT: "import projects into workspace" worked for me, but why was that necessary?

Comment: Did you actually [import](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm) the project into Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in the directory are not automatically picked up by the package explorer.  You need to import them.

Try using the File > import, then choose

```
Existing Projects into workspace.
```

There is a checkbox that says "Copy projects into workspace" which copies it to your workspace if it happens to be in a different folder.  If you start with your files in another folder, you'll see how it's copied and set up with configuration files in your workspace directory.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, "why is it necessary to import?" you have to realize that [the Eclipse workspace is just a logical container for projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9841397/639520), not necessarily the physical container for them.

Also realize that a directory of project-related files does not make an Eclipse Project; Eclipse must be given or generate it's own set of configuration in order to understand a project (minimally, for Java projects, `.project` and `.classpath`). Without those, Eclipse has no idea what to do with an arbitrary folder that you call a "project." That's what the *Import* or *Create Project* wizards are doing under the covers, generating those config files.