# How to find where a specific project is stored | Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, store, workspace

I know how to see and change my workspace. But how do I see where a specific project is stored. Its not stored in my workspace, because its an old project, and I recently changed my workspace.

Comment: Check this answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9838349/5566543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project and select properties. Under General (top tab) you will see Resources. The Location will be listed to the right.